# Fallout 4 is there a hight limit for buildings in settlements

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

In fallout 4 on the ps4 I have been finishing up on a original 3X3 house that holds up to 15 beds each floor (thats if you really dont want to  get though the door once its built). This desing however is designed to go infinite floors (each floor being 1 wall high). I was wondering if there is a hight limit for how many floors you can place so I know before I go resource farming so I can make a rough estimate for how much wood steel and cotton I will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a hight limit. Every settlement has a different maximum.

Build wooden stairs on top of each other until you can't build more - that's when you hit the ceiling.

Comment: Covenent's is obnoxiously short, the prebuilt houses are taller than the limit. Made it hard for me to get up to 21 settlers and fit in the food, water, and generators to run my wall of lasers. I hope some DLC includes a better generator, or I'll just find a mod that does it.

Comment: You can send settlers from other settlements there.

Comment: It's not a problem with recruitment, it's a problem with bed space. Even stuffing the existing buildings full of beds doesn't get you to 21 and leave enough space to avoid pathing issues. I built a platform across the whole place to get a second level for shacks to solve the problem, but I usually go higher with turret towers and such. My Hangman's Alley is three levels tall to fit everyone in.

Comment: I have 27 settlers there

Comment: Maybe your settlers behave better, mine always seem picky about where I put the beds.